# React native wheel picker view(IOS Type view)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, picker, react-native-picker

**Any package recommendation are helpful which provide similar view for both (android and iOS) similar to https://github.com/TronNattakorn/react-native-wheel-pick**

Note: I am currently using https://github.com/TronNattakorn/react-native-wheel-pick  for Scrollable Wheel View but this package further uses https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker which have open issues like this https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker/issues/168.
**But JCenter completely shut down in Feb 2022. I am looking for other options which can be used** .

**Another recommended option** : https://github.com/react-native-picker/picker
But this one provide different view for android and iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at a package called `react-native-picker-select`, and you can find  a preview example [here](https://snack.expo.dev/@lfkwtz/react-native-picker-selecthttps://)

Comment: Tried this, it provides wheel view for ios only.